# MS Outlook 2016 hanging when trying to receive email: imap-login: Debug: SSL error: read failed: Connection reset by peer

Tags: dovecot, outlook-2016

I have a postfix/dovecot server. My client uses MS Outlook 2016 via imap to check email. Everything was fine until today when send/receive stopped working and would just hang.

I had client clear everything out of "send" folder and subscribe/unsubscribe from folders. Nothing worked. When the client shuts down outlook and reopens, I see these entries on the mail server:

```
1465625 Aug 31 16:23:31 email dovecot: imap(wtait)<4374><HUE/RY/nwts2VTBm>: Logged out in=91 out=1012 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
1465626 Aug 31 16:23:32 email dovecot: imap(wtait)<4372><wc0WRY/nwmlKYboC>: Debug: Mailbox Drafts: Mailbox opened because: SELECT
1465627 Aug 31 16:23:32 email dovecot: imap(wtait)<4372><wc0WRY/nwmlKYboC>: Debug: Mailbox INBOX: Mailbox opened because: SELECT
1465628 Aug 31 16:23:32 email dovecot: imap(wtait)<4372><wc0WRY/nwmlKYboC>: Debug: Mailbox INBOX: UID 37236: Opened mail because: prefetch
1465629 Aug 31 16:23:32 email dovecot: imap(wtait)<4372><wc0WRY/nwmlKYboC>: Debug: Mailbox INBOX: UID 37236: Opened mail because: access
1465630 Aug 31 16:23:32 email dovecot: imap(wtait)<4372><wc0WRY/nwmlKYboC>: Debug: Mailbox INBOX: UID 37236: Opened mail because: full mail
1465631 Aug 31 16:23:32 email dovecot: imap(wtait)<4372><wc0WRY/nwmlKYboC>: Debug: Mailbox Sent: Mailbox opened because: SELECT
1465632 Aug 31 16:23:32 email dovecot: imap(wtait)<4372><wc0WRY/nwmlKYboC>: Debug: Mailbox Trash: Mailbox opened because: SELECT
1465633 Aug 31 16:23:32 email dovecot: imap(wtait)<4372><wc0WRY/nwmlKYboC>: Debug: Mailbox Trash: UID 52: Opened mail because: prefetch
1465634 Aug 31 16:23:32 email dovecot: imap(wtait)<4372><wc0WRY/nwmlKYboC>: Debug: Mailbox Trash: UID 52: Opened mail because: access
1465635 Aug 31 16:23:32 email dovecot: imap(wtait)<4372><wc0WRY/nwmlKYboC>: Debug: Mailbox Trash: UID 52: Opened mail because: full mail
1465636 Aug 31 16:23:32 email dovecot: imap(wtait)<4372><wc0WRY/nwmlKYboC>: Debug: Mailbox Trash: UID 53: Opened mail because: prefetch
1465637 Aug 31 16:23:32 email dovecot: imap(wtait)<4372><wc0WRY/nwmlKYboC>: Debug: Mailbox Trash: UID 53: Opened mail because: access
1465638 Aug 31 16:23:32 email dovecot: imap(wtait)<4372><wc0WRY/nwmlKYboC>: Debug: Mailbox Trash: UID 53: Opened mail because: full mail
1465639 Aug 31 16:23:32 email dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL error: read(size=896) failed: Connection reset by peer
```

The client can login with web-based email with no problems. I think this is probably an MS Outlook problem but not sure how this might be fixed.

Comment: Could you distinguish "crashes since last outlook update was applied" from "crashes because it does not have the latest outlook security update applied"?

Comment: I cannot find it right now, but there is a guide somewhere about how to completely reset outlook to start as if it was a fresh user profile.

Comment: You probably tried a few times, so does the log point repeatedly pinpoint the same message or folder as the last processed item?

Comment: Is the time correct? Did you try remove the outlook profile and re-create?